# read-only `top` in linux?

Tags: linux, top, htop

I have a few servers with an application for some clients, and I want to make an application available for the client to view the server and application status, and to be able to restart some services.

I already have done the major part of it, replacing the login shell of a ssh user with a custom shell script that presents him a menu with some options to do that. The menu is launched automatically with `sudo` (with `NOPASSWD`) once he logs in, because the script needs to restart system services. The problem is that I'd like him to view the output of `top` or `htop`, but I don't want him being able to kill or renice processes and maybe other things that both `top` and `htop` permits. I just want him viewing the output of `top`.

Is there any option, flag or equivalent command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `top`'s `secure mode`, when it is invoked as

```
top -s
```

In that mode the user can't change the refresh delay of top, `kill` or `renice` processes.

If you want to make it system wide instead of on a per-invocation basis, you may use the `/etc/toprc` file with the following contents:

```
s
3.0
```

Only two lines: first one to set `secure-mode`, and the second to set the refreshing delay. You can have a `~/.toprc`, but its syntax is different from the system-wide `/etc/toprc` and you can't set secure mode in there.

I can't find a similar option in `htop`.